# I keep Getting error: 'arr[$i] is not a valid identifier' on bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm practicing Fibonacci series on bash script with arrays and for loop but I got this error

```
jrnl6T2.sh: line 10: `arr[$i]': not a valid identifier
```

Here is .sh file

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p "Enter term: " term

arr[0]=0
arr[1]=1
for (( i=2; i<$term; i++))
do

    arr[$i]= expr $((arr[$i-2]+arr[$i-1]))
    
done

for (( j=0; j<$term; j++ ))
do
    echo ${arr[$j]}
    
done
```

As I'm a beginner so not sure why I am getting this error. I have google this problem also but did not find appropriate solution. I am using ubuntu 20.04.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two wrong things in the expression calculation statement:

1. You have put a space character after the `=` sign. You cannot use whitespace before or after the *equals sign*.
2. `expr` is a command. To capture and assign its output, you need to enclose it in [`$()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), like this:

   ```
   arr[i]=$(expr $((arr[i-2]+arr[i-1])))
   ```

   or

   ```
   arr[i]=$(expr ${arr[i-2]} + ${arr[i-1]})
   ```

   <sup>Please note that the `expr` command in the first case does nothing; the [`$(())`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) construct calculates the expression.</sup>

However, I suggest you do Bash arithmetic operations using the `let` command.

Your script can be corrected like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter term: " term
let arr[0]=0
let arr[1]=1
for (( i=2; i<term; i++ ))
do
  let arr[i]=arr[i-2]+arr[i-1]
done
for (( j=0; j<term; j++ ))
do
  echo ${arr[j]}
done
```

Another alternative (which is equivalent to the `let` command, but I would not prefer) is this:

```
arr[i]=$(( arr[i-2] + arr[i-1] ))
```

Comment: can you explain why did you change `arr[$i]` with `arr[i]`. I have checked, both term gives the same output

Comment: I think this is coming from Korn Shell. See end of section 6.4.1 at https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_04.htm